# About existence of a meromorphic function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that if $F$ is a meromorphic function on a complex compact riemann surface $C$, than $F$ will have a finite number of zeros and poles and $F$ will have the same number of zeros and poles.
If we take $p_1,...,p_k$, and $q_1,...,q_t$ a finite number of points on $C$, is it possible to construct a meromorphic function with zero in $p_1,...,p_k$ and poles in $q_1,...,q_t$?

Comment: Yes, do you know Riemann-Roch ?

Comment: yes i've found that theorem. $h^{0}(D)-h^{1}(D)=deg(D)-g+1$. But if i have a finite number of points like in the question what does tell me the RRT about the existence of a meromorphic function that have such points as zeros and poles?

Comment: can you be more explicit?

Comment: Take $D=n(p_1+\cdots+p_k)-(q_1+ \cdots+q_t)$ for $n$ big enough (so that $h^1(D)=0$).